# filter multiple lists in angular4 with custom pipes

Tags: angular

I have two components with in admin.component usernames who i can filter, in vragen.component i can't filter, its the same HTML. Why can't I access vragenSearch.

Angular Html

```
<div class="container-fluid">
            <ul>
                <div *ngFor=" let vraag of resultsvragen | sort | filter : vragenSearch; let i = index">
                <li [ngClass]="{'omkringd': vraag.username == this.dataService.UserName, 'omkringdTwee': vraag.username !== this.dataService.UserName }"  (click)="onSelect(vraag, vraag.vraagID)"
                  [ngStyle]="{'background-color':this.markeer[vraag.vraagID]? '#47d147':'none'}">
                   {{vraag.username+": "}} {{vraag.tekst}}
                   <div *ngIf="!this.upvote[vraag.vraagID]">
                        <button class="btn btn-success" (click)="Upvote(vraag.vraagID)"><i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                    </div>
```

Angular Html

```
 <ul>
            <div *ngFor="let user of allUsers | filter : usersSearch; let i = index">
            <li>
                {{ user.voornaam + " : " }}  
                <div *ngIf="user.leerkracht">Admin</div>
                <div *ngIf="!user.leerkracht">
                    Geen admin    
                    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" name="maakAdminButton" (click)="maakAdmin(user.id)">Maak admin</button>
                </div>
            </li>
        </div>
        </ul>
```

Angular filter pipe

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({
    name: 'filter'
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(items: any[], usersSearch: string, vragenSearch: string){
        if (items && items.length){
            return items.filter(item =>{
              if (usersSearch && item.voornaam.toLowerCase().indexOf(usersSearch.toLowerCase()) === -1){

                    return false;
                }
                if (vragenSearch && item.tekst.toLowerCase().indexOf(vragenSearch.toLowerCase()) === -1){
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
           })
        }
        else{
            return items;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your code snippets, you are trying to pass two different search parameters to your filter pipe. Be aware that the parameters are not named!

Only the order of your parameters matter. Check the usage of multiple pipe parameters here:
https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/pipes/using_pipes.html

So even if you have that code:

```
let user of allUsers | filter : vragenSearch;
```

The value of vragenSearch will be still passed as usersSearch into your filter pipe.
https://v2.angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html